# ngx-intl-tel not supporting mulitple binding at once

Tags: angular

I tried to bind countrycode and contactnumber in ngx-intl-tel but got this issue
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '123123'. Current value: 'undefined'.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @vahidtajari here is my .ts code
  this.consigneeInfo.CountryId = res.result[0].countryCode;
this.consigneeContact = res.result[0].contact

Comment: <ngx-intl-tel-input
 [cssClass]="'form-control'"
 [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false"
 [enablePlaceholder]="false"
 [searchCountryFlag]="true"
 [searchCountryField]="[
   SearchCountryField.Iso2,
   SearchCountryField.Name
 ]"
 [selectFirstCountry]="false"
 [selectedCountryISO]="consigneeInfo.CountryId"
 [maxLength]="15"
 [tooltipField]="TooltipLabel.Name"
 [phoneValidation]="true"
 [separateDialCode]="true"
 name="consigneeInfoContact"
 [(ngModel)]="consigneeContact"
 [disabled]="!consigneeInfo.IsEdit"
 (keypress)="Spaceregex($event)">
</ngx-intl-tel-input>